# Angular event or command that signals the end of processing child directives

Tags: angularjs, angular-directive

I'm currently coding a tab navigation example to gain practical experience with Angular. This example uses custom directives and controller inheritance.

Plunker can be found [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/IDazM3wiVxJ5VnJm4s4q).

The issue: once the directives have finished processing I'd like to select a default tab to display. But at the point of calling the `selectTab` method of the `myTabs` controller (line 41 in *script.js* `$ctrl.selectTab(0)`), Angular hasn't yet finished processing the `myTab` directive (which generates the tab links), so the `tabs` array is empty and the selection fails.

I tried using $timeout without a delay, but that fails. $timeout only works with a delay of say 500ms set, which is hacky.

Is there an event or command available that signals the end of Angular processing certain directives, particularly directives that inherit from one another?

What I suspect is happening:

The `myTabs` directive finishes processing then fires its link function, but it's fired before the `myTab` directive is done processing. I can't place the `selectTab` method call within the `myTab` link function because would get called multiple times (based on the number of tabs processed.) Hope I'm explaining this clearly...I need a massage

```
app.directive('myTabs', ['$timeout', function($timeout) {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        transclude: true,
        controllerAs: 'myTabsCtrl',
        templateUrl: 'my-tabs.htm',
        scope: {},
        controller: function ($scope) {

            vm = this;

            this.tabs = [];

            this.addTab = function (tab) {
                this.tabs.push(tab);
            };

            this.selectTab = function selectTab (tabIndex) {

                for (var i = 0; i < this.tabs.length; i++) {

                    this.tabs[i].selected = (i === tabIndex ? true : false);

                }

            };

        },
        link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl) {

            $timeout(function () {
                $ctrl.selectTab(0);
            });

        }
    };

}]);

app.directive('myTab', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        require: '^^myTabs',
        transclude: true,
        templateUrl: 'my-tab.htm',
        scope: {
            title: '@'
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ctrl){

            scope.tab = {
                title: scope.title,
                selected: false
            };

            ctrl.addTab(scope.tab);

        }
    };

});
```

Comment: This appears to be the root cause: "For each directive, its controller and pre-link function executes before the controller and pre-link function of its child directives"

Comment: It does that because the directives are using `templateURL` which fetches templates asynchronously. If the directives used `template`, it would be a different story..

Answer (score 0):

Each individual tab is registering itself with the parent directive controller. Simply set the `selected` flag on the first tab when it registers itself:

```
this.tabs = [];
this.addTab = function (tab) {
    console.log("add tab ", tab);
    if (!this.tabs.length) {
        //Set flag for first tab to register
        tab.selected = true;
    };
    this.tabs.push(tab);
};
```

The [DEMO on PLNKR](https://plnkr.co/edit/w7mEF44IPIzBXEKivlVA?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you George but I'm interested in discovering how to track the final DOM rendering for a nested directive template so that a single call can be made to do whatever, such as set a default tab in this case. The reason for wanting to know if this can be achieved is because I predict it'll be an issue when build full-scale apps in the future.

Answer (score 0):

AngularJS 1.5.3 introduced the `$postLink` life-cycle hook:

> ### Life-cycle hooks
>
> Directive controllers can provide the following methods that are called by Angular at points in the life-cycle of the directive:
>
> - `$postLink()` - Called after this controller's element and its children have been linked. Similar to the post-link function this hook can be used to set up DOM event handlers and do direct DOM manipulation. Note that child elements that contain **templateUrl directives will not have been compiled** and linked since they are waiting for their template to load asynchronously and their own compilation and linking has been suspended until that occurs.

--[AngularJS $compile Service API Reference -- Life-cycle hooks](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile#life-cycle-hooks)

The `$postLink` life-cycle hook won't work in this case because the directives use `templateUrl`. It also won't work with directives that build DOM after postlink; `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, `ng-include`, etc.

Comment: As a side question, am I right in understanding that the term 'link' means to attach the elements to the DOM? e.g. "Called after this controller's element and its children have been linked."

Comment: Yes, with the exception of `ng-repeat`, `ng-if`, `ng-switch`, and other directives that do manual transclusion.